# Deploy a Spring Boot application which uses ActiveMQ from Docker to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, activemq-classic

I have a Java Spring Boot application which uses ActiveMQ from a [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq/). It is now completed. Now how to deploy it to Heroku?

The application is based on ActiveMQ. So I also need to deploy it.

Comment: @JustinBertram both.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing to be exact. That is my question how to do this ? I can deploy the application and run ActiveMQ in my localhost but my application will be down in that case. So What to do ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is really for programming questions, and that's not what your question is about. I think you're better off asking your question on a something like https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heroku.

Comment: Also, it's customary for folks to actually attempt to perform the task they're asking about before seeking help. I'm sure Heroku has some kind of documentation aimed at helping users deploy their applications. I recommend you start there and see how far you get. If you hit road-blocks then you can ask specific questions about the process you're following. It's much easier to answer specific questions than broad questions like what you're asking here.